Draw two concentric circles without any change in stroke in Adobe Illustrator
I need to draw two concentric circles and I followed this procedure -
Ellipse tool →shift+drag→select→
(Ctrl+C+F)→shift+alt+drag any node(outward for bigger circle and inward for smaller).
But the problem is that for big circle stroke is bigger than the smaller circle but I want both strokes to be the same. How to do that?

Either just change the stroke for all circles afterwards or enter Preferences and untick General > Scale Strokes & Effects.

Select both circles, open up the Main menu → Window → Stroke panel and type your stroke value in the weight field.

